# ¿Cómo es que se puede cambiar los valores de una lista en C#?

Tags: c#, windows-forms, datagridview

tengo una duda con un código de C#.

***Código de C#***

```
    private void BtnAceptar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                CategoriaProducto cat;
                if(this.actual == null)
                {
                    cat = new CategoriaProducto();
                    Program.Categorias.Add(cat);
    
                }
                else
                {
                    cat = this.actual;
                }
                
                cat.Nombres = this.TxtNombre.Text;
                cat.Descripcion = this.TxtDescripcion.Text;
                cat.Vigente = this.ChkVigente.Checked;
                
                this.DgvListado.DataSource = null; //Disvincula el datagridview
                this.DgvListado.DataSource=Program.Categorias; //Vincula el datagridview con la colección categorias
                this.HabilitarControles(false);
            }
```

La variable "this.actual" funciona de la siguiente manera: Cuando le doy clic en el botón "Nuevo" la variable "this.actual" toma el valor "null" y cuando le doy clic en el botón "Modificar" la variable "this.actual" toma el valor del objeto seleccionado en el DataGriedView.

***Código del Botón "Modificar"***

```
private void BtnModificar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CategoriaProducto seleccionado;
            if (this.DgvListado.CurrentRow != null)
            {
                seleccionado = (CategoriaProducto)this.DgvListado.CurrentRow.DataBoundItem;
                this.PresentarDatos(seleccionado);
                this.actual=seleccionado;
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Debe seleccionar una categoria", this.Text);
            }
        }
```

Ahora mi duda esta en mi "Código C#" y es que cuando la variable "this.actual" es null:

1. Instacia la clase CategoriaProducto.
2. Agregar el objeto "cat" a la lista Categorias(la clase Catergorias lo cree en la clase Program) pero este objeto lo agregada con los valores vacios.

***Clase Program***

```
namespace POO
{
    internal static class Program
    {
        //colección para guardar categorias de producto
        public static List<CategoriaProducto> Categorias = new List<CategoriaProducto>();
        /// <summary>
        /// Punto de entrada principal para la aplicación.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }
    }
}
```

3. En este paso agrega valores al objeto "cat" los cuales tienen atributos de: Nombres(string),Descripcion(string) y Vigente(boolean).
4. Luego los visualiza en el DataGriedView.
   Ahora mi duda viene aqui, como es posible cambiar los valores del objeto si esta se agrego en una lista, porque según el "Código de C#" no veo algo que vuelva agregar los valores cambiados porque si ya los agrego vacios pero aún asi C# si los visualiza. No sé como hace para visualizarlo esa es mi duda. Espero que me entiendan.

Comment: Tu problema es teorico.. cuando agregas el objeto a la lista, en realidad, estas diciendole a la lista que agregue ese puntero a ese objeto.. pero vos tenes el puntero tambien en otra variable, con lo cual, al cambiarla, cambia el contenido de la lista. La lista no hace una copia del objeto.. usa el mismo objeto...

Comment: @gbianchi O sea,la Lista trabaja con punteros verdad o no.

Comment: todo son punteros en c# (o casi, pero no podrias diferenciarlos)